# how to get the TOC of word document use POI or use docx4j?

Tags: apache-poi, docx4j, tableofcontents

i have a trouble this days, i cant get the TOC of word use poi,and i try to use
docx4j to read the word document,but i cant find a function to get it,some one knows how to get the toc of word document ?

Answer (score 0):

[TocFinder.java](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/toc/TocFinder.java) is part of docx4j 3.3.0;  docx4j 3.3.0 can generate and update a table of contents.

TocFinder will find a TOC in a content control which is the way Word makes them these days.  You'd need to adapt it if you wanted to find a TOC which wasn't in the content control.